# What to do when a question is migrated here but it really doesn't belong?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15981/two-divs-one-fixed-width-the-other-the-rest) in particular caught my attention. I think it's been well established at this point that CSS questions involving code belong on SO so I am unsure why it was migrated here. What should we do when something like this occurs?

Comment: Do your moderator tools allow you to bounce it back?

Comment: It does. I'm just unsure if that's the right approach as it is my understanding that the powers that be frown upon multiple migrations.

Answer (score 2):

You could bounce it back with apologies and a comment linking to this question: [What is the status of HTML/CSS layout questions on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85675/what-is-the-status-of-html-css-layout-questions-on-so)

Unless you're aware of a way of contacting the moderator there who bounced it here, there's probably not much more you can do.